# Unexpected result from "bm.faces.new(verts)"

Tags: python

I'm trying to use "faces.new()" to fill a hole in mesh, Strangely when I use the function the newly create face looks like this:

[image]

Code:

```
import bpy, bmesh

obj = bpy.context.object.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.active_object.data)

v = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]

bm.faces.new(v)
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj)
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the normals and directions of the normals. Recalculate if needed with Ctrl+N whilst on edit mode

Comment: @ReubenX Checked the normals and recalculated it, but no difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The contextual create operator.**

Rather than calculate the winding order to create face with `bm.faces.new(verts)` let the operator do it for you.

**[bmesh.ops.contextual_create](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.contextual_create)**

> Contextual Create.
>
> This is basically F-key, it creates new faces from vertices, makes
>   stuff from edge nets, makes wire edges, etc. It also dissolves faces.
>
> Three verts become a triangle, four become a quad. Two become a wire
>   edge.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

ob = bpy.context.edit_object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)

verts = [v for v in bm.verts if v.select]
bmesh.ops.contextual_create(bm, geom=verts)

bmesh.update_edit_mesh(me)
```

Answer (score 2):

The order that vertices are listed when defining the face, determines the order that they are connected. [This tutorial](http://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/python-2d-grid/) can help explain it.

Say we have four vertices to make a face, with indexes of 0,1,2,3 going clockwise.

```
bm.faces.new([v[0], v[1], v[3], v[2]])
```

will give you the bowtie effect that you have, while

```
bm.faces.new([v[0], v[1], v[2], v[3]])
```

will give you the square face you are expecting.

I expect the only way to automate this is to walk around the selection to determine the connected order. A vertex lists what edges it creates in [`link_edges`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMVert.link_edges), from `vert[0]` an edge that includes another selected vert gives you the second vert, then that vert has an edge with another selected vert...